# cypher query - check for a relationship if not present check for another one

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to check if a relationship exist from a node, and in case its not found, then i want to check for another relationship type from the same node.

Something like, ***(a:Type)-[:relation1]-(b)*** if relation1 exist query **returns node b**.  If **not exist**, then will check for another relationship like, ***(a:Type)-[:relation2]-(b)*** and returns **node b**.

I want to know how this can be writen as a single cypher query. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use COALESCE() to make a backup choice in case the node at the first relation is null.

```
// after you've already matched to a
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:relation1]-(b)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:relation2]-(c)
WITH a, COALESCE(b, c) as b // will use node c if b is null
...
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using a UNION ?

```
MATCH (a:Type)-[:relation1]-(b)
RETURN b
UNION
MATCH (a:Type)-[:relation2]-(b)
RETURN b
```

Hope it helps,
Tom